# How do I create my own django model field to store data in multi columns or related table

Tags: python, django, django-models

Help me find more complete examples of creating my own model fields, in special articles or simple examples from the source code.
First of all interested about store data in several columns of table or store or in a linked table.

Comment: Can you please explain you question? If it is you are asking how to create models in Django, you can refer [Create Django Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/)

Comment: I'm want something like django-modeltranslation or django-parler. In source of django-modeltranslation not yet watched, but django-parler source to hard for me.